# Phone number clean up from parsed CSV file

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. I am trying to parse phone numbers from a CSV file and I did that using the following code. It is working properly.

```
require 'csv' 
csv_text = File.read('file.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|                                      
    puts "Home Phone: #{row['HomePhone']}"
end
```

What I want is to clean up HomePhone in the following ways.

1. If phone number has 10 digits, it is good, print it as such.
2. If phone number has less than 10 digits, print invalid number as “0000000000”
3. If phone number has 11 digits and first digit is 1, print last 10 digits (remove first 1), else “0000000000”

I don't know how to do this.

Comment: What happens if it has 11 digits and the first digit is not 1, or if it has more than 11 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the length of a string with the aptly-named `length` method:

```
string = 'foobar'
string.length # => 6
```

You can check if a string starts with another string using `start_with?`:

```
string.start_with?('f') # => true
```

You can slice a string individual characters using array index notation (square brackets) and a range. A negative index counts from the end of the string. So to return all but the first character:

```
string[1..-1] # => 'oobar'
```

So to do what you are asking you can combine these

```
home_phone = row['HomePhone']
if home_phone.length == 10
  puts home_phone
elsif home_phone.length == 11 && home_phone.start_with?('1')
  puts home_phone[1..-1]
else
  puts '0000000000'
end
```

Note that this approach assumes that your phone numbers are already strings of digits and you just need to check their length. If you wanted to be more thorough and check for invalid phone numbers containing non-digits, like `123z567890`, you might consider a regex approach:

```
if match = /^1?(?<number>\d{10})$/.match(row['HomePhone'])
  puts match[:number]
else
  puts '0000000000'
end
```

The components that this regex matches are:

- `^` - the start of the string
- `1?` - an optional `1`
- `(?<number>\d{10})` - 10 digits (ie `\d{10}`) saved in a group called `number`
- `$` - the end of the string

Ruby uses the forward slashes to delimit the regex, and the `match` method returns an object that we can use to extract the saved 10-digit number.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
csv.each do |row|
   phone_number = row['HomePhone'].to_s
   if phone_number.length == 10
     puts "Home Phone: #{phone_number}"
   elsif phone_number.length == 11 && phone_number[0] == "1"
     puts "Home Phone: #{phone_number[1..10]}"
   else
     puts "Home Phone: 0000000000"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

put this into your each block:

```
phone_number = row['HomePhone']
if phone_number.length == 10
  puts "Home Phone: #{row['HomePhone']}"
elsif (phone_number.length == 11 and x[0] == "1")
  phone_number.slice!(0)        # remove first character
  puts phone_number
else
  puts "0000000000" 
end
```